# Objectlistview doubleclick explained

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I'm trying to implement the `doubleclick` function in an `objectlistview` object.

According the developer, one should use `ItemActivate` instead of `MouseDoubleClick`.

So I came up with this:

```
    private void treeListView_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ListView.SelectedIndexCollection col = treeListView.SelectedIndices;

            MessageBox.Show(col[0].ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e3)
        {
            globals.logfile.error(e3.ToString());
            globals.logfile.flush();
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

Which comes up with a value for each double clicked row.
But how do I get the details from that row?

Here's the whole solution I'm now using:

```
    private void treeListView_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var se = (StructureElement)treeListView.GetItem(treeListView.SelectedIndex).RowObject;
            MessageBox.Show(se.id.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e3)
        {
            globals.logfile.error(e3.ToString());
            globals.logfile.flush();
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Citation for the developer's recommendation of ItemActivate: https://sourceforge.net/p/objectlistview/discussion/812923/thread/6dac409d/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which comes up with a value for each double clicked row. But how do I get the details from that row?

I think you have to access the `RowObject` using the underlying `OLVListItem` like this:

```
private void treeListView_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var item = treeListView.GetItem(treeListView.SelectedIndex).RowObject;     
}
```

Comment: Hi Rev1.0, thank you for your answer, I can see the data in the item object now.

Now I need to figure it out how to retrieve each individual value.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. You have to cast the `RowObject` to your corresponding model type to access the properties.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand
I've got 
    public class StructureElement
    {
        public string remoteId { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
}

Comment: you could also do: ```var item = treeListView.SelectedObject;```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm now getting the data out of the treelistview:

```
private void treeListView_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var se = (StructureElement)treeListView.GetItem(treeListView.SelectedIndex).RowObject;
        MessageBox.Show(se.id.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception e3)
    {
        globals.logfile.error(e3.ToString());
        globals.logfile.flush();
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```