# ObjectListView Make Image clickable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, objectlistview

I'm using ObjectListView is there a way to make the image clickable or the object in the row clickable? So it works like a button

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770863/objectlistview-doubleclick-explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way and that's to use CellClick.

```
  objectListview1.CellClick+= ObjectListview1_CellClick;
```

Then the function uses HitTest to see column was pressed.

```
  private void ObjectListview1_CellClick(object sender, CellClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.HitTest.ColumnIndex == 3) {
            //Code here 
        }
    }
```

Hope this help anyone with the same problem